# Why do I have to include the primary key column in this insert statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-ce, sql-server-express

Given a SQL Server Express Compact Edition database with a table called "Clients" with the following columns:

```
ID, FirstName, MiddleName, Nickname, LastName, Suffix, IsMale
```

where ID is an auto-incrementing primary key / identity value, when I try to use this command on the table:

```
INSERT INTO Clients (Title, FirstName, MiddleName, Nickname, LastName, Suffix,
IsMale) VALUES ('', 'John', '', '', 'Smith', '', 'True')
```

everything works.  But when I try to use this command:

```
INSERT INTO Clients VALUES ('', 'John', '', '', 'Smith', '', 'True')
```

this error shows up:

```
The number of columns in the query and the table must match. [ Number of columns
in query = 7, Number of columns in table = 8 ]
```

I've been using insert statements with SQL Server for quite a while now, and this has never been a problem; the validation against the number of columns has always ignored auto-incrementing primary keys / identitity types.  The only major difference in this case is that I'm now using a very low-end version of SQL Server, whereas I'm used to using much more professional versions.  In case it might possibly matter, I am using this in a C# program.

What would be causing this?   Thanks.

EDIT: A lot of the focus of this question is the fact that I never have run into this problem when using the non-free, non-compact versions of SQL Server.  The SQL Servers I've used before have ALWAYS been smart enough to ignore the identity / primary key column in the column count, and to just figure out the auto-incremented value without me having to spell out specific column names.

Although another difference here is that I've always used SQL Management Studio to mess with table definitions before, whereas I'm going through VS 2012 and SQL Server Compact Edition in this case.  The user interfaces involved are obviously pretty different, so I guess maybe there's something being specified for the table or something when you do it in Management Studio that keeps this problem from happening?

Comment: See (and follow!): [Bad habits to kick : using SELECT * / omitting the column list](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list) - it's considered a best practice to always explicitly specify the column list - both in a `SELECT` as well as an `INSERT` statement

Comment: This [does work](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/22c6d/2). The issue must be something else. (For instance, your ID is not really an IDENTITY but is instead handled by a trigger.) Having said that, I agree with the comment by @marc_s.

Comment: " I'm now using a very low-end version of SQL Server, whereas I'm used to using much more professional versions" - more detail please

Comment: SQL Server Compact Edition Express, whereas, even though I've forgotten exactly what it's called, we tend to use a completely full-fledged SQL Server 2012 at work, complete with SQL Server Management Studio.  Even though I don't remember the names precisely, the one I'm using here is the free version of the compact edition, whereas I'm generally used to using the expensive versions that are non-compact.  I'm not at work right now, so I can't look up the exact name.

Comment: @Andriy: I see it working on that link, but it won't work when I put it in my own code.  I changed the table name to Clients2.  Then it didn't seem to recognize the varchar datatype or something (which shouldn't be possible, right?), so I changed them to nvarchars.  Other than that, I didn't change anything, but I still get that error.  What's so different?

Comment: That might be something Compact Edition-specific (if that's really what your server version is), but I couldn't tell for sure. Never worked with Compact Edition, and as for those versions I *have* worked with, don't remember ever encountering this kind of issues.

Comment: Andriy, post your last comment as an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't specify the columns in the insert statement then it takes all the columns into consideration. Even if one of the column is auto increment.

[Insert - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx)

> column_list must be used when **explicit values are inserted into an
>   identity column**, and the SET IDENTITY_INSERT option must be ON for
>   the table.

Comment: Yes, but by default, the autoincrement column is treated same as computed columns when you haven't provided the column list, meaning that you must specify values for all "normal" columns only. Meaning, in turn, that the OP's statement should work *if* ID is indeed an IDENTITY column (which I doubt very much at the moment, or else there's something they have forgotten to mention).

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to write the INSERT INTO statement in two forms.

The first form doesn't specify the column names where the data will be inserted, only their values:

```
INSERT INTO table_name
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
```

This will work only if the number of values provided match the number of columns **exactly**

The second form specifies both the column names and the values to be inserted:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
```

This is the form that has to be used, even if there is an ID column of identity type.

Raj

---

Comment: For some reason, I've always seen it work anyway when using expensive, non-compact versions of SQL Server / SQL Management Studio.

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to mention that the table `Clients` have a column name `Title`. The first query works because you have explicitly define the values for the columns you have specified in the statement.

The second one failed because you are using `Implicit` type of `INSERT` statement. When using that type of `INSERT`, you must specify all values for all columns in the table. Since the first column in the table is `ID` and it is `Auto_Increment`ed, `NULL` can be used to substitute the value.

```
INSERT INTO Clients VALUES (NULL, '', 'John', '', '', 'Smith', '', 'True')
```

Answer (score 0):

i think ' ' represents an empty string which one can't be inserted into a integer value

so you can specify NULL instead of ' '